# how to make a sqoop job iterative by catching the tables from the sqlserver?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Hi i have multiple tables in the sql server. can i use a select statement to list tables and make the sqoop job iterative by catching the tables. and create hive schema.
I have tried using sqoop import-all-tables but it didn't worked.
can you please provide me with some documentation to go through.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  There is a way of using sqoop direct command.

Try the following, below. It may help you:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename --username $USER_NAME$ --password $PASSWORD$ --exclude-tables table1, table2 -m 1
```

Comment: @EugenePodskal I don't see a link anywhere in this answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, my bad. Was overly trigger-happy in VLQ.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop supports importing all the tables together with some limitations. Please check this link:

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal

Comment: but there are some limitations that every table should be associated with primary key kind off.
soo looking for an alternate.
thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the database name alone will help your issue by fetching all tables from it.

```
  sqoop import-all-tables --connect [SQLserver connection string/Database Name]
```

Comment: but there are some limitations that every table should be associated with primary key kind off.
soo looking for an alternate.
thanks for the feedback.